# How can WSGI get the URL that called it?

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, gunicorn, wsgi

My problem seems to have been discussed in a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978795/getting-url-from-wsgi-script), but had no working answer.

I need to, in the WSGI python file, before actually starting Django, analyze the URL that was called and 'read' it, so I can know who called it and extract information from there that I can use to determine how my Django app will be started.

I have an app running on a VM that is called from several different URLs, each pointing to a different WSGI file, all running the exact same code in Django, but using different 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' files. A different settings file for each URL that calls my application. This is a legacy project which I cannot alter. Currently, this is how it operates:

- User1 accesses 'user1.example.com' > WSGI sets DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to settings_user1 > WSGI starts Django
- User2 accesses 'user2.example.com' > WSGI sets DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to settings_user2 > WSGI starts Django
- User3 accesses 'user3.example.com' > WSGI sets DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to settings_user3 > WSGI starts Django

Each URL calls for a different WSGI file, all running the same project, but setting the variable to the appropriate SETTINGS.

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings_user1")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

We're moving away from Amazon, where our VM is currently located, and plan on using Google AppEngine instead, but we're not quite sure on how to point to a different settings file depending on the URL called, if using the same project/version.

We can simply use a different version of our AppEngine for each URL, and then have the URL called be 'user1-dot-example.appspot.com', hardcoding the settings file onto the wsgi for each version... but that would require starting different instances for each URL.

Expecting to be able to, before starting the Django app, obtain the string 'user1' when accessing my App through the URL 'user1.example.com', and the string 'user2' when accessing my App through the URL 'user2.example.com' (original URL, that will be redirected to AppEngine using CloudFlare), so I can do somethign like this:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
url = SOME_CODE_THAT_GETS_THE_URL_HERE()
user = url.split('.example.com')[0]
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings_{}".format(user))
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Is there anyway WSGI can retrieve the URL that called the API? Or perhaps even a way for gunicorn to pass it to the WSGI in a variable, somehow getting the '$URL' variable and doing something like this:

```
gunicorn -b :$PORT wsgi:create_app(url=$URL)
```

Or even a way to get the URL into an environment in app.yaml from AppEngine would already solve the problem. All that is needed is to have the variable before Django is actually set up with the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Comment: WSGI processes are usually started **before** any requests are passed to them. Why do you need separate processes/settings ?

Comment: I have 200 different customers, and each of them has different attributes on their DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE files. I've currently created one app.yaml on AppEngine for each of them, pointing to a different DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE file. It works, but then I have to have several different versions of my app running, one for each customer. The customer is denoted in the URL though (as in my post. user1.example.com), so it could possibly be retrieved from said URL?

Comment: What are the major differences for each customer/app? It may be possible to just pass environment variables to each process that your settings file reads

Comment: I'm not sure if I am understanding your use case, but you would like to redirect a user based on a subdomain (i.e. myuser1.example.com). Is there a special need for doing this? This sounds like you would need 100 different settings for 100 users, and so forth. Wouldn't it be more scalable and efficient that you have a specific subdomain for each view? (i.e. login.example.com, home.example.com, or even admin.example.com) and then not sure if this applies to your use case, but you could even restrict access to certain views to different user roles.

Comment: Also, it may be worth checking out [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) files. You can use it to send incoming requests to a specific service or module bsaed on the path or hostname in the URL. Examples can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#example). Let me know if this helps you at all.

Comment: @IainShelvington Simple variables: user name, customer database (each customer has it's own DB), some specific strings. Yes, it is possible. Tt would be possible to pass it there, but then the 'user1.example.com' needs to redirect the user accordingly to the desired service. I've tried passing the variables that way, but some of them have special characters (Âãá) that could not be interpreted by AppEngine and caused it to crash, so I ended up having to set them on different settings, and point to the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as an environment variable in the end.

Comment: And yes, @sllopis, that would be more efficient and scalable. Problem is, we're already making a new platform from scratch to solve all these issues, but we need to keep the legacy version running as is until then as we migrate to Google Cloud Platform. We're using dispatch, but it can only configure up to 20 routes (and we have over 200). We ended up creating several projects (>10), each with one dispatch and only 20 customers. Definitely not scalable or efficient, but it works until we can deploy the new version of our platform.

Comment: I think here there could be some useful materials for the URL reconstruction - https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#url-reconstruction